# access structure members with variables

Tags: c++, struct

There is structure

```
struct Person{
int age;
string name;
string sex;
};

struct Person p1={23,"alice","male"};
```

Generally we access the value using p1.age or p1.name
But I want to access using variable.

```
string name="p1";
string item="name";
```

Now Can I get value of p1.name using variables:name and item

If not is there any way to get using pointers.

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve by this? What's the use-case? Your question is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for help with a predetermined solution to an (for us) unknown problem. Perhaps there are other ways to solve your problem?

Comment: there were many structures and members defined in this structures. To get value of particular member of structure in generic way. (not directly mapping required key to p1.name using if..else or switch) Want to implement using generic function implementation.

Comment: the "generic way" to access a member called `name` of an instance called `p1` is `p1.name` ....

Comment: but those p1 and name are given by some variables... they will be different for different cases

Comment: you need to show us your use case. It definitely sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I had to implement a function such that it takes one variable(key) as input and gives its value as output. The value is defined and initialized in one of many structures there in other cpp file. Cannot directly map the key to its value like(p1.name). Need to implement in generic way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way of doing this unless you provide a run-time `std::string` to object mapping in your program. C++ doesn't have any run-time reflection built-in that would allow you to do this.

An alternative is using *pointers* to refer to existing variables and data members. E.g.

```
auto object = &p1;
auto member = &Person::name;

std::cout << object->*member << '\n'; // prints "alice"
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8oydjsstIDuuHLWB)

Comment: Can you please provide example of how to implement in run time

Comment: @VSK this is all runtime. It would really help if you would explain why you think you need something like that